Jwt authentication fails 401 after upgrading to .net8
I having following startup code
        services.AddAuthentication(opt =>
            {
                opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = false,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
                    NameClaimType = "uid",
                    ValidateActor = false,
                    ValidateSignatureLast = false,
                    ValidateTokenReplay = false,
                    ValidateWithLKG = false,
                    SignatureValidator = (token, parameters) => new JwtSecurityToken(token)
                };
            });
            services.AddAuthorizationBuilder()
            .AddPolicy("WithUserIdOnly", policy => policy.RequireClaim("uid"));

But since I have upgraded to .net8, I always get a 401 response.
and Api looks like this:
[ApiController]
[Authorize(Policy = "WithUserIdOnly")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Resp>> Get()
    {}
}


It will be solved by changing from System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JsonWebToken
